# mysql stored procedure in from clause

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to include a stored procedure which returns rows in `FROM` clause of a `SELECT`

The code for the SP is something like this:

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE tirar (IN param1 INT)
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE id=param1;
END;
```

This works fine executing: `CALL tirar(7)`

But, is it possible to include this SP in FROM clause of a `VIEW`? 
Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tirar WHERE id=7;
```

phpmyadmin returns a 1064 error executing it, and I'm not sure that it works on a php program file.

Comment: Sorry. The question is: But, is it possible to include this SP in FROM clause of a VIEW? Like this:

SELECT * FROM tirar(7);

Comment: No, it's not. You better ask how to achieve what you want to...

Comment: Well, I try to ask it in other way.
Maybe with parameters views.

How can be created one view with another view in FROM clause which has parameters in WHERE clause (the second or nested view)?

I mean:
SELECT id1 FROM (SELECT id2 FROM table2 WHERE id2=9)

Comment: How about you just have a try?